# Is it possible to use Grunt task target name inside attributes?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, task

I'm using the `grunt-replace` task to replace some content inside the index.html file. But I want to avoid code duplication as much as possible. The following code snippet does not work as it is, but it's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
replace: {
    options: {
        patterns: [
            {
                match: /<(script.*?src=)"(?![\w/]+environment)/g,
                replacement: '<$1"//<%= config.cdn[target] %>/'
            }
        ]
    },
    a: {
        files: [
            {
                src: '<%= config.path.dist.output %>/index.html',
                dest: '<%= config.path.dist.output %>/index-a.html'
            }
        ]
    },
    b: {
        files: [
            {
                src: '<%= config.path.dist.output %>/index.html',
                dest: '<%= config.path.dist.output %>/index-b.html'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I call `replace:a` I want the replacement pattern to come from `config.cdn['a']` and when I call `replace:b` I want the replacement pattern to come from `config.cdn['b']`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `'<%= targetName %>'`? Why are you not just putting variable `targetName` directly as value for `myAttribute`?

Comment: @MattiMehtonen I re-wrote the whole question. It didn't made much sense before. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little bit ugly, but it could work or at least help a little bit:

```
replace: (function () {

    var exports = {},
        targets = ['a', 'b'],
        target,
        i,
        j;

    for (i = 0, j = targets.length; i < j; i++) {
        target = targets[i];

        exports[target] = {
            options: {
                patterns: [
                    {
                        match: /<(script.*?src=)"(?![\w/]+environment)/g,
                        replacement: '<$1"//' + config.cdn[target] + '/'
                    }
                ]
            },
            files: [
                {
                    src: config.path.dist.output + '/index.html',
                    dest: config.path.dist.output + '/index-' + target + '.html'
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    return exports;

}())
```

Comment: I want to avoid to mix JS code in tasks like that, but maybe that's the only solution :(